# Javascript to disable Explorer Sound on Refresh in IFrame

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, audio

I have a javascript in an iframe that rotates banners every 10 seconds. When the iframe refreshes, explorer plays a sound when the new image appears.  Can anyone point me to a liberary or example script to disable the playing of the explorer sound in the web page?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can, you should instead change/"rotate" the banner on-the-fly without reloading/refreshing the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can not change the sound by javascript as it is done by the program itself. You could use javascript  to just change the source of the image.

```
<img id="MyImg" src="/someimage.jpg">
```

```
<script>
document.getElementById("MyImage").src = "/Someotherimage.jpg";

</script>
```

Comment: yup, just like my comment said!